# How identity constraint works?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Could any one suggest me how can i make 10 as increment in the below statement.

```
create table Student1(SID int primary key identity(0,10),SName varchar(10))
```

Comment: 10 **is** the increment!

Comment: But when i insert a name into the table. The ID get incremented by 1.

Comment: No, it doesn't... You must have done something wrong...

Comment: Your table definition is working just fine. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/113839/

Comment: Yes. Sorry for posting question like above, with out checking. Thanks alot for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax is `IDENTITY [ (seed , increment ) ]`. You need to specify both or none. The default is `(1, 1)`